# php login form adds _x_ to email address

Tags: php, oscommerce

I know I have encountered this before but using oscommerce the login for adds a *x* to some email addresses.

example being metal turns into me_x_tal  and I just cant remember what I did last time to fix this. if I remember correctly its trying to parse it as another language? any ideas?

thanks in advance

Comment: i realize this is a very old post of mine but wanted to answer what we found as I forgot to way in back in the day.
in Oscommernce the cross site scripting filter replaces certain lines of text with the string and an _x_ in it to keep it from being injected into the database as malicious code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i realize this is a very old post of mine but wanted to answer what we found as I forgot to way in back in the day. in Oscommernce the cross site scripting filter replaces certain lines of text with the string and an x in it to keep it from being injected into the database as malicious code